# program that takes a string as input from user from command line and printing only list of unique characters

Tags: perl, hashcode

How to parse the string's individual character for eg " =-. lajadsfdddll ooo532333 ksfoiww0etu - " /.> W#H^*!@#~ nsa@". and add each individual character into hash and then count as ohw many times each character has apeared and the only unique character.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

As it sounds very much like a homework question, I'll try pushing you in the right direction. Hopefully you know how to take in a line of user input. In this case, your very general algorithm will look like this:

```
1. Take the input
2. Parse the input into individual characters - Think about Perl built in methods
3. Add characters to the Hash and count. 
4. Iterate through the Hash and print the relevant data.
```

Character counting is a pretty common problem in a variety of languages, so utilizing Google will be your friend. Also consider that Hashes associate a Key with some value, and only stores unique keys, but it can store any value type.

Additionally, the Perl Cookbook has a recipe on the free online book that discusses how to read individual characters of a string, and this tutorial can be found in a variety different sites.

Long story short, there are plenty of resources out there to answer this problem, and you'll learn more if you go out and find them.